# Rails: How to dynamically create path for singular nested resource using polymorphic_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some singular nested resources and the entries for them looks like this:

```
resources :rocs, only: [:show] do
  resource :r1_response, :r2_response, :r3_response, :r4_response :r5_response do
    member do
      get :print
    end
  end
end
```

Now I want to dynamically generate paths for my nested singular resources like below:

```
print_roc_r1_response_path
print_roc_r2_response_path
...
```

I am trying to use `polymorphic_path` to generate above paths:

```
link_to "Print ROC", polymorphic_path([:print, @roc, controller.controller_name])
```

But it's giving error: `undefined method print_roc_r1_responses_path` cause `controller.controller_name` is **plural**. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
resources :rocs, only: [:show] do
  resources :r1_response, :r2_response, :r3_response, :r4_response :r5_response do
    member do
      get :print
    end
  end
end
```

Change resource to resources

Comment: I want to use singular resource only.